# use of %d is giving strange rounding values in Awk program

Tags: awk, floating-point

I am getting strange answer when I am performing sum on certain set of records.
in one case i am not using the %d and in the next case i am using the %d

the first expression of sum of using %d

```
 awk -F"|" '(NR > 0 && NR < 36) {sum +=$150} END {printf ("%d\n",sum)}' muar.txt
-|33
```

without %d

```
 awk -F"|" '(NR > 0 && NR < 36) {sum +=$150} END {printf ("\n"sum)}' muar.txt
-|34
```

Why it is rounding to 33 from 34

Just to add more Info, till 34 row I am getting sum as 33.03 and the  35th row has value 0.97 so actually it should be 34 rather than 33

Additional Detail as per Comments for Testing -you can create a file let's a.txt
having Only One Field. the first value is blank  second one is 1.95 then 18 times 097 in a row, then 0.98 then 6 times 0.97 then 0.98 then 3 times 0.97  then 0.98 2 times then 2 times 0.97

Or You can have 1.95 - 1 time , 0.97 - 29 times, and 0.98 4 times all one below other in a row

Comment: try to create a minimal example that we can test at our end... for ex: `awk 'BEGIN{printf "%d\n", 33.03+0.97}'` and `printf '33.03\n0.97\n' | awk '{s+=$1} END{printf "%d\n", s}'` both gives `34` for me..

Comment: may be when you print up to 34th row,  sum is actually something like `33.029`... what is output you get if you use `printf "%.5f\n", sum` ?

Comment: It could be interesting to see the output of `awk -F"|" '(NR > 0 && NR < 36) { print $150 }'` (added to your question). Then we can test with the actual numbers.

Comment: `1.95 - 1 time , 0.97 - 29 times, and 0.98 4 times` yup, this allows to replicate the issue.. I see same result with awk/perl... only guess I can make is this is related to floating point arithmetic.. you can use `printf "%.0f\n", sum` as a workaround.. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131073/awk-printf-number-in-width-and-round-it-up

Comment: @Sundeep - Thanks Sundeep ".0f\n works but was just intrigued with this issue that  is why I  have posted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to your question is *two fold*:

- There is a numeric problem
- `awk` does some internal conversion

One of your examples was : 1.95 + 29*0.97 + 4*0.98. We can all agree that the sum of this value is 34 exactly. The little `awk program below, does the computation in two different ways leading to remarkable results :

```
awk 'BEGIN{sum1=1.95 + 29*0.97 + 4*0.98
           sum2=1.95;
           for(i=1;i<=29;i++){sum2+=0.97};
           for(i=1;i<=4;i++) {sum2+=0.98};

           printf "full precision     : %25.16f%25.16f\n",sum1,sum2
           printf "integer conversion : %25d%25d\n"      ,sum1,sum2
           printf "string conversion  : "sum1" "sum2"\n"
}'
```

which leads to the following output (first column `sum1` second column `sum2`

```
full precision     :       34.0000000000000000      33.9999999999999787
integer conversion :                        34                       33
string conversion  : 34 34
```

**Why do the two sums have different results:**

In essence, the 3 numbers `1.95`, `0.97` and `0.98` cannot be represented in a binary format. An approximation occurs which represents them as

```
1.95 ~ 1.94999999999999995559107901499...
0.97 ~ 0.96999999999999997335464740899...
0.98 ~ 0.97999999999999998223643160599...
```

when summing them as is done according to `sum2`, the errors of the 33 additions grows and leads to the final result :

```
sum2 = 33.99999999999997868371792719699...
```

The error on `sum1` is much smaller than `sum2` as we only do 2 multiplications and 2 additions. In fact, the error evaporates to the correct result (i.e. the error is smaller the `10^-17`):

```
   1.95 ~  1.94999999999999995559107901499...
29*0.97 ~ 28.12999999999999900524016993586...
 4*0.98 ~  3.91999999999999992894572642399...
   sum1 ~ 34.00000000000000000000000000000...
```

For a detailed understanding of the above, I refer to the obligatory article [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

**What is happening with the print statements?**

`awk` is essentially doing internal conversions:

- `printf "%d"` requests an integer, but it is served a float. `awk` is receiving `sum2` and converts it to an integer by removing the fractional part of the number, or you could imagine it feeds it trough `int()` Thus `33.99999...` is converted to `33`.
- `printf ""sum2`, this is a conversion from a float to a string. Essentially by concatenating a string to a number, the number has to be converted in a string. If the number is a pure integer, it will just convert it as a pure integer. However, `sum2` is a float.

  The conversion of `sum2` to a string is internally done with `sprintf(CONVFMT,sum2)` where `CONVFMT` is an awk built-in variable which is set to `%.6g`. Thus `sum2` is by default rounded to be represented with a maximum of 6 decimal digits. Hence `""sum2 -> "34"`.

**Can we improve `sum2`:**

Yes! `sum2` is nothing more than a representation of a sequence of numbers we want to add. It is not really practical to search for all the common terms first and the use multiplications as is done in `sum1`. An improvement can be achieved using [Kahan Summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm). The idea behind it is to keep track of a compensation term representing the digits you lost.

The following program demonstrates it:

```
awk 'BEGIN{sum2=1.95;
           for(i=1;i<=29;i++){sum2+=0.97};
           for(i=1;i<=4;i++) {sum2+=0.98};
           sum3=1.95; c=0
           for(i=1;i<=29;i++) { y = 0.97 - c; t = sum3 + y; c = (t - sum3) - y; sum3 = t }
           for(i=1;i<=4;i++)  { y = 0.98 - c; t = sum3 + y; c = (t - sum3) - y; sum3 = t }

           printf "full precision     : %25.16f%25.16f\n",sum2,sum3
           printf "integer conversion : %25d%25d\n"      ,sum2,sum3
           printf "string conversion  : "sum2" "sum3"\n"
}'
```

which leads to the following output (first column sum2 second column sum3)

```
full precision     :       33.9999999999999787      34.0000000000000000
integer conversion :                        33                       34
string conversion  : 34 34
```

If you want to see the intermediate steps and difference between `sum2` and `sum3` you can check out the following code.

```
 awk 'BEGIN{ sum2=sum3=1.95;c=0;
             for(i=1;i<=29;i++) {
                sum2+=0.97;
                y = 0.97 - c; t = sum3 + y; c = (t - sum3) - y; sum3 = t;
                printf "%25.16f%25.16f%25.16e\n", sum2,sum3,c
             }
             for(i=1;i<=4;i++) {
                sum2+=0.98;
                y = 0.98 - c; t = sum3 + y; c = (t - sum3) - y; sum3 = t;
                printf "%25.16f%25.16f%25.16e\n", sum2,sum3,c
             }
      }'
```

Comment: @kunal.Gaurav The simplest way is `printf "%50.40f" 0.97`. The hard way is to compute the binary representation directly according to the [IEEE standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). This leads to (for a float `x>0`)  `Floor(x*2^(52-Floor(Log[2,x])))*2^(Floor(Log[2,x])-52)`

Answer (score 0):

@kvantour : if you want the EXACT internal binary representation of IEEE 754 doubles, `mawk-1` has an undocumented feature that makes it really easy :

```
mawk 'BEGIN { 

    CONVFMT = OFMT = "754::%.16lX"
        OFS = ORS

    print \
        exp(1),
    -atan2(0, -1),
         5 / 3,
     .5 + 5.^.5 * .5,

     2^(1024 - 53) * (2^53 - 111),

     cos(atan2(1, 1)),

             -log(0),
              log(0),
       log(0)-log(0),
     -(log(0)-log(0))    }'
```

---

```
754::4005BF0A8B145769      # Euler's e = 2.71828...
754::C00921FB54442D18      # Negative pi

754::3FFAAAAAAAAAAAAB      # Integer fraction
754::3FF9E3779B97F4A8      # Golden Ratio

754::7FEFFFFFFFFFFF91      # Largest prime below 2^53 scaled 
                           # to max precision-retaining exponent
754::3FE6A09E667F3BCD      # cosine of pi / 4

754::7FF0000000000000      # +infinity
754::FFF0000000000000      # -infinity

754::7FF8000000000000      # +NaN
754::FFF8000000000000      # -NaN
```