# How to remove decimal pints in bash script?

Tags: bash, awk

I have tried following code to print memory usage in %.. It print the answer as follow,

71.2505 - I need the answer as 71% ..how can I resolve this ?

```
free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100}'
```

Comment: `val=$(free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100}'); echo ${val%.*}`

Comment: `awk '{print int($3/$2 * 100)}'`

Comment: Or, `free | grep Mem | awk '{printf "%d\n",  $3/$2 * 100}'`

Comment: suggestion: `grep` functionality can be done with `awk` too... `free | awk '/Mem/{..}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least three options so far. (1) capture the output from the *command substitution* in a variable and then use simple *parameter expansion with substring removal* to discard up to the decimal from the right, e.g.

```
val=$(free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100}'); echo ${val%.*}
```

Next as @melpomene suggested, using the int(...) operation with `awk`

```
awk '{print int($3/$2 * 100)}'
```

Finally, you can use `printf` with the `%d` *format specifier* to discard the decimals as well, e.g.

```
free | grep Mem | awk '{printf "%d\n", $3/$2 * 100}'
```

(**note:** another, and perhaps better *format specifier* in place of `%d` would be `%.0f` to preserve the floating point character, while trimming the additional decimals)

Either one will do.

Comment: Glad it helped -- you even had a choice of picks. Good luck with your scripting.

Comment: `%.0f` might be better choice than `%d`... see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808474/use-of-d-is-giving-strange-rounding-values-in-awk-program

Comment: Yes that is another option and if bash tracked UB, then it would be superior. Will add that as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` isn't needed:

1. *POSIX* shell method, (*i.e.* `bash`, `dash`, *et al*):

   ```
   free | { read; read a b c d; echo $((c*100/b)); }
   ```
2. *POSIX* shell:

   ```
   set -- `free` ; echo $(($9*100/$8))
   ```
3. Pure `bash`:

   ```
   m=(`free`) ; echo $((m[8]*100/m[7]))
   ```